# Exactly when can a player "on hold" interrupt another character?

Tags: combat, savage-worlds, interrupt

It says you can interrupt the "Action" of a character when you are on hold--for simplicity let's assume the interrupting character was dealt a joker.

Here are a few increasingly unlikely-to-be-legal scenarios to indicate what "Interrupting an action" actually means:

1. Can a character on-hold interrupt a walking action as a character
   walks by?  Does that attack stop the walk action?
2. Suppose a character is invisible and turns visible as he attacks a
   teammate, can the on-hold joker then run up and attack the
   previously invisible character before he hits?  If he kills the
   previously invisible character, does it still get it's attack
   (simultaneous)?
3. Can the on-hold joker wait to see if someone hits then interrupt him
   before he rolls damage?
4. Can the on-hold joker see the damage roll and kill the attacker
   before the character being attacked takes the damage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes you can interrupt partway through another character's movement,
   and depending on what you do it is perfectly possible to stop their
   movement completely.
2. Yes you can interrupt the character when they become visible. If you
   kill them, they do not get the chance to even attempt to hit your
   teammate as you interrupted before the attack happened.
3. No you cannot interrupt here. The damage happens as a consequence of
   the hit, so you would need to interrupt to prevent the hit from
   happening.
4. Again, this is not possible as you would need to interrupt to
   prevent the attack in the first place.